Sdk.targets not found error - dotnet linux
Sdk.targets not found error - dotnet linux
Issue:
Running a dotnet build on linux jenkins agent and have Sdk.targets not found error
Error:
/apps/jenkins-agent/agent/workspace/rk_CHATBOTS_Dotnet_Deploy_master/src/ChatBot.csproj : error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/Sdk/Sdk.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/Sdk/Sdk.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
What was tried

Checked path on agent and path exists and valid
/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/Sdk/Sdk.targets
Set environment variable
export MSBuildSDKsPath='/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Sdks/'
Verified if agent is picking up this path and it does (docker info shows it picks up base path)
Base Path:   /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/

Still having the errors.
Commands trace
+ dotnet --version
8.0.103
+ dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.103
 Commit:            6a90b4b4bc
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.e99a2be4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     rhel
 OS Version:  8
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         rhel.8-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/

.NET workloads installed:
 Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.e99a2be4
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.3
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       9f4b1f5d66

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.214 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.128 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
  8.0.103 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.28 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.3 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.28 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.3 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/apps/jenkins-agent/.dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
+ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.214 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.128 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
8.0.103 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
+ cd /apps/jenkins-agent/agent/workspace/rk_CHATBOTS_Dotnet_Deploy_master/src
+ dotnet publish -c release -o /apps/jenkins-agent/agent/workspace/rk_CHATBOTS_Dotnet_Deploy_master/appdeploy --no-restore
MSBuild version 17.8.5+b5265ef37 for .NET
/apps/jenkins-agent/agent/workspace/rk_CHATBOTS_Dotnet_Deploy_master/src/ValriRootBot.csproj : error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/Sdk/Sdk.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/Sdk/Sdk.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

